# installing lalsuite to conda

Tags: package, conda, development-environment

im trying to install lalsuite on conda https://github.com/conda-forge/lalsuite-feedstock

attempt 1 = conda-forge

```
(base) C:\Users\jack.flavell>conda install -c conda-forge lalsuite
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining python=3.9: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 4/4 [00:01<00:00,  3.56it/s]-                                                                                                                       |failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

doesn't work + it states some packages aren't compatible but doesn't say which.

attempt 2 = messing with channels

```
(base) C:\Users\jack.flavell>conda config --add channels conda-forge

(base) C:\Users\jack.flavell>conda config --set channel_priority strict

(base) C:\Users\jack.flavell>conda install lalsuite
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.-
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

result from 2 ,similar to 1.

attempt 3 = use conda forge as part of my create env command

```
(base) C:\Users\jack.flavell>conda create -n gwe3 -c conda-forge -c lalsuite
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: lalsuite
  channel url: https://conda.anaconda.org/lalsuite
  error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

so i do what message said in attempt 3

```
(base) C:\Users\jack.flavell>conda config --show channels
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

and no idea what to do next...

any idea how to install lalsuite? please?

##########################

extra info

1. ive tried python 2.7, 3.6, 3.10
2. ive read about many compatibility issus with lalsuite. eg no pip version < 18.

And so below is information about my environment from conda. it seems within the parameters ive seen around.

| package | build |
| --- | --- |
| bzip2-1.0.8 | h8ffe710_4 149 KB conda-forge |
| ca-certificates-2022.9.24 | h5b45459_0 189 KB conda-forge |
| libffi-3.4.2 | h8ffe710_5 41 KB conda-forge |
| libsqlite-3.39.4 | hcfcfb64_0 642 KB conda-forge |
| libzlib-1.2.12 | hcfcfb64_4 71 KB conda-forge |
| openssl-3.0.5 | hcfcfb64_2 7.8 MB conda-forge |
| pip-22.2.2 | pyhd8ed1ab_0 1.5 MB conda-forge |
| python-3.10.6 | hcf16a7b_0_cpython 16.5 MB conda-forge |
| setuptools-65.4.1 | pyhd8ed1ab_0 776 KB conda-forge |
| tk-8.6.12 | h8ffe710_0 3.5 MB conda-forge |
| tzdata-2022d | h191b570_0 118 KB conda-forge |
| ucrt-10.0.20348.0 | h57928b3_0 1.2 MB conda-forge |
| vc-14.2 | hac3ee0b_8 14 KB conda-forge |
| vs2015_runtime-14.29.30139 | h890b9b1_8 1.2 MB conda-forge |
| wheel-0.37.1 | pyhd8ed1ab_0 31 KB conda-forge |
| xz-5.2.6 | h8d14728_0 213 KB conda-forge |

##############

update

attempt 4

I thought using conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" lalsuite  would point specifically to a version, and so shouldn't fail. I got the link from here https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/lalsuite

however the output I get is

```
(wge3) C:\Users\jack.flavell>conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" lalsuite
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

conda search confirms the package is there...

```
(wge4) C:\Users\jack.flavell>conda search lalsuite
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
lalsuite                        6.57            py_1  conda-forge
lalsuite                        6.60            py_0  conda-forge
................
```

why the bloody hell does this not work?

what does it want?

what more info might help answer

arrrrrgggghhhhh >:(

######## update 2

I was under the impression that anything on pypi can be downloaded with pip. like here https://pypi.org/project/lalsuite/.

Below is just in a regular cmd not using conda

```
C:\Users\jack.flavell>"C:\Users\jack.flavell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" install lalsuite
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lalsuite (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lalsuite
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\jack.flavell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

... apparently not ...

should things be available on pip if i find them on pypi?

Answer (score 0):

turns out it doesnt work on windows,i need linux